# PHP Query string present, but empty GET

Tags: php, get, query-string

On my site, one of my pages when loaded never contains a GET value.

The beginning of the script is:

```
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_SERVER);
```

For `$_SERVER` I get:

```
REQUEST_URI => /dir/sub_dir/script_name/?s=30&v=20
QUERY_STRING =>
```

and for `$_GET` I just have: `Array ( )`

This doesn't seem to be a problem for any other page.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Can't you access by index/key the values?

Comment: I have a few quick questions: do you have any .htaccess URL rewriting taking place? Is the script being included from another script? What happens if you access the script with as `/dir/sub_dir/index.php?s=30&v=20`?

Comment: My first thought would be that you are using url rewrite to route pages to scripts and are missing the `QSA` flag in the RewriteRule. `QSA`="query string append". Meaning that any additional get string passed is also added to the url rewrite.

Comment: Are you using a framework? This happens a lot with MVC frameworks, including CakePHP.

Comment: @GigaWatt, I edited my question, I left out the part of the `script_name` which is included in the query. It is not an index page, but the URL is re-written via `.htaccess` to remove `.php` and add `/`. Sorry for not mentioning that. I use the same rewriting rules for other scripts without problems.

Comment: @WaffleStealer654, I am not using a framework. @JonathanKuhn, I have the `QSA` and it works for other scripts just fine.

Comment: @Jakar - It's a shot in the dark, but does the script work correctly if you disable the URL rewriting?  It'll help determine if the issue is PHP itself or the web server messing with things.

Comment: I had my .htaccess files locally deleted and I forgot that in one of the sub directories, I did have a .htaccess with some deny/allow rules and that for some reason was breaking the GET but nothing else. Oops. Either way it's fixed now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question would be -50 if asked by a newbie

Comment: @NickMaroulis, I admit, it was terribly careless. It was extremely puzzling up until I remembered the extra .htaccess, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my `.htaccess` files locally deleted and I forgot that in one of the sub directories, I did have a `.htaccess` with some deny/allow rules and that for was breaking the GET but everything else was loading. Deleting the `.htaccess` (or fixing it to allow properly) made the `GET` values start working again.